# Centering Image Inside Navigation Bar

Tags: css, html, navigation, html-lists

This code works great for centering a Navigation Bar when it is just text.  Both Horizontally and Vertically.

But when I try use an image for the Home (house image) - it offsets and is no longer centered in the middle vertically.

```css
.navt {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}
.navt li {
  display: inline;
}
.navt a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
}
.navt li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navt">
  <li>
    <a href="_index.cfm">
      <img src="../images/hm_wht_tr30.png" height="20" border="0">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.cfm">This</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.cfm">And</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.cfm">That</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.cfm">Here</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.cfm">There</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align:middle`?

Answer (score 0):

If you add `.navt img { vertical-align: middle; }` you make the image align vertically in regards to the text.

```css
.navt {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}
.navt li {
  display: inline;
}
.navt a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
.navt li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: pink;
}
.navt img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navt">
  <li>
    <a href="_index.cfm">
      <img src="../images/hm_wht_tr30.png" height="20" border="0">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.cfm">This</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.cfm">And</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.cfm">That</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.cfm">Here</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page.cfm">There</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked mostly.  Just getting a black border under the text on the hover. Not on image - it's hover is clean top/bottom. So text has bottom border of a bit.  Is this a sizing issue with image?

Comment: The image is higher than the text. I've added both a height and a line-height (to vertically center it) to the text and removed the vertical padding. The image was 20px high plus two times 12px padding makes for a total of 44px of height